# Listview/Datagrid binding from query generated list

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, dapper

So I have a query that returns values from multiple tables with a left join.
But I can't seem to get the data from left join table.

```
public IEnumerable<TipsTricks> GetTipsTricks()
        {
            using(var connection = new SqlConnection(Connection.Instance.ConnectionString))
            {
                return connection.Query<TipsTricks>(@"SELECT tt.ID, cat.Omschrijving, tt.Info, tt.Onderwerp, tt.Firma FROM tblTipsAndTricks as tt
                                                      LEFT JOIN tblTT_Categorieen as cat on cat.Id = tt.CategorieID ");
            }
        }
```

I then do in code behind to bind it to Datagrid.ItemsSource:

```
        public void initialize()
        {
            List<TipsTricks> tipstricks = DatabaseManager.Instance.TipsTricksRepository.GetTipsTricks().ToList();
            DgTipsTricks.ItemsSource = tipstricks;
        }
```

Class TipsTricks

```
    public class TipsTricks
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Info { get; set; }
        public string Onderwerp { get; set; }
        public string Firma { get; set; }
        string Omschrijving { get; set; }
    }
```

Also tried the binding in de XAML without succes.

So I would like a column in the datagrid showing the content of cat.Omschrijving from the left join table tblTT_Categorieen.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making the property string Omschrijvin "public"

as shown below

```
  public class TipsTricks
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; }
    public string Onderwerp { get; set; }
    public string Firma { get; set; }
    public string Omschrijving { get; set; }
}
```